# Put SEO and Twitter card Meta tags in the Head section prior the render of the template

Tags: php, seo, meta

I need to put some `<meta />` tags in the `<head />` section of the html document prior the rendering of the template. I would like to know how can I achieve this? I also need to query an external database in order to get some data from it and populate the meta tags. What I want to accomplish is to pass a link to my website and get Twitter to display a card with the image, description, etc.

What is the best option in order to accomplish this task? a Plugin? a Controller? a Module? Does anybody know any good tutorial or guide in order to do this?

I'm using CraftCMS ver 3.4.9

Thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [plugin that allows you to connect to an external database](https://plugins.craftcms.com/connect), which will allow you to do a query within the template. Remember to cache the result though as it could slow things down otherwise.

Another option is to sync the external data with Craft using [feed me](https://plugins.craftcms.com/feed-me), so you can pull the data locally.

Comment: What about to get the data first prior the template rendering? How do I get to do this? a Plugin? a Module? a Controller? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can create a module with a controller that can render a template: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/controllers.html#rendering-templates